Should a PhD statement of purpose focus on what you accomplished during previous research experiences or what you learned via these experiences?
I'm applying for PhDs in mathematics (in the USA). I've read a number of statement of purpose examples from friends and from those online. Generally, I see two different approaches to writing about previous research experiences:
(1) Some people focus on the hard facts of what they and their colleagues did during a research project, saying things like "we were interested in XYZ question, so we successfully used ABC methodology to show ZYX results".
(2) Others seem to focus more on the broader lessons that they extracted from a research experience: "Working with a large group on XYZ, I learned how to more effectively collaborate with peers... the process of doing ABC enhanced my ability to communicate ideas clearly and concisely".
Which approach should be prioritized in a statement of purpose? I feel like approach (1) is more straight to the point. I've read online that its bad to be overly flowery and expository in writing a PhD SOP, which (2) runs the risk of. But at the same time, I feel like in order to write 500-1000 words following approach (1), one has to go into considerable depth about their research, and I've read online that its bad to get too bogged down in explaining the minute details of one's research (using specific technical jargon that may not be familiar to everyone on the admissions board etc...).

Actually, I find neither of those approaches compelling. The SoP isn't about the past. The CV is for that. The SoP should be about what you want to accomplish in the future, both in grad study and in a career.
It should say what sub-field(s) you intend to follow (usually one or two) and, when possible, what problem(s) you think you would like to attack. It should, however, be flexible. Insisting on one problem with no options is sub-optimal. You will need to find an advisor at some point and negotiate a problem area with them, so you need to be "interesting" to the faculty.
I'll note, however, it is normally very difficult for an incoming doctoral student in mathematics to be very specific about a problem. That is expected, since it is the common case. But you should be clear about the sub field. In my case I preferred real analysis (old school, as am I) but would be happy in topology. That was enough, though a bit more refinement might have been good.
Use the past only to support the future and make such statements about your past brief and to the point. "I want to focus on A, and my previous work as detailed in the CV has led me here." A bit more focus than that, but not a lot more words.
The CV is about where you have been. The SoP is about where you hope to go, with something about how you hope/expect to get there. Put your (1) in the CV and most of your (2) in cover letters and such.
